# How to find the element with rating count on rakuten

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm unable to find the ratings (number next to the stars) at [rakuten website](https://www.rakuten.com.tw/shop/pandq/product/?l-id=tw_shop_inshop_cat&p=1) the pic showed below.

I try to use `beautifulsoup` to locate the element, but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
import time
import requests
!pip install beautifulsoup4
import bs4
!pip install lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}

products =[]
for i in range(1,2): # Iterate from page 1 to the last page
    url = "https://www.rakuten.com.tw/shop/pandq/product/?l-id=tw_shop_inshop_cat&p={}".format(i)
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    Soup = soup.find_all("div",class_='b-mod-item-vertical products-grid-section')

    for product in Soup:
        productcount = product.find_all("div",class_='b-content')
        print(productcount)
```

Comment: First of all, check if this element is being returned in html response or it's being rendered using javascript API request. In the second case you cannot scrap this element using this method, because this element simply does not exist in your request response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happens?

Selection of element is not that proper, so you wont get the expected result.

#### How to fix?

As your Screen shot shows different things `price` / `rating` I will focus on rating.

First select all the items:

```
soup.select('.b-item')
```

Then iterate the result set and select the `<a>` that holds the `rating`:

```
item.select_one('.product-review')
```

Get rid of all the special characters:

```
item.select_one('.product-review').get_text(strip=True).strip('(|)')
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www.rakuten.com.tw/shop/pandq/product/?l-id=tw_shop_inshop_cat&p=1',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for item in soup.select('.b-item'):
    rating = item.select_one('.product-review').get_text(strip=True).strip('(|)') if item.select_one('.product-review') else None
    print(rating)
```

#### Output

```
5
36
21
32
8
...
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks a lot. It’s really helpful. However, if the “rating”does not exist, could I use a condition or exception to exclude it ?

Comment: Happy to help - Take a look added a condition to the example, that checks if element is there, if not it will return None